# Angular ng-class directive not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this issue where I try to color `some` of the list items in an ionic list. `somearray` is an array holding the indices to be colored red. No matter what, this below code is coloring only `the first index in the array`. Where's the problem?

```
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-class="{red : !somearray.indexOf($index)}" ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="item" >
              <div>
                <button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="addNewForm($index)">
                  {{todo.title}}
                </button>
              </div>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `somearray.indexOf($index)` will return the index which only 0 will be false so only the first row will be red.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, stupid mistake. It should've been `red : somearray.indexOf($index)!==-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the item cannot be found or the index of the element when it is.

You can check that the return value of `indexOf` is greater than -1 instead:

```
{red : somearray.indexOf($index) > -1}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [{title: 'a'}, {title:'b'}, {title:'c'}, {title: 'd'}];
  $scope.somearray = [1,2];
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-class="{red : somearray.indexOf($index) > -1}" ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="item" >
              <div>
                <button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="addNewForm($index)">
                  {{todo.title}}
                </button>
                {{$index}}
              </div>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
</div>
```